# How to check which session is registered in PHP?

Tags: php, session, web-applications

I am creating a site and I'm using sessions to manage the user log in status. When a user logs in, I create a session id for the user like so:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = "username";
```

How can I check if a user is logged in, and if so, who it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, after you have authenticated the user you are writing `$_SESSION['username']` to the the [session superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), all you need to do is double check the existance of a session username:

```
 session_start()
 if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
      // user is not logged in
 }
```

Figuring out who is logged in is as simple as checking what username you have stored in the `$_SESSION['username']` variable that we checked earlier.  If you wanted to save their real name from a database result, or other information, just dump that information into the `$_SESSION['data_type']` array as well.

The session variables should automatically expire in 24 minutes (PHP default, I think) of inactivity, in which case you should expect the user to login again.  If you want to log the user out immediately, check out [session_destroy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

Comment: The configuration value session.gc_maxlifetime governs session length, the default value, oddly, is 24 minutes (1440 seconds).